# How can I get number of property with SWRL rule in Protege

Tags: protege, swrl

I want to write a rule to get the number of assets owned by a network and check if it is greater than 3. So I wrote the SWRL rule as:

```
Network(?n)^(hasAsset\>3)(?n)-\>NetworkhasManyAssets(?n)
```

But the Protege says "Unexpected character `\>`"

---

How to modify the rule.

Comment: `hasAsset>3` that is not a valid SWRL syntax operator, see the SWRL specs and chose the proper comparison atom: https://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/#8.1

Comment: Yes, I also notice that, but could you tell me more detail about how to construct the right one. I check the link you posted. I found one possible rule like:
Artist(?x) & (≤1 artistStyle)(?x) & creator(?z,?x) ⇒ (≤1 style/period)(?z)
So I wrote the rule as:
Network(?n)^(>3 hassAsset)(?n)->NetworkhasManyAssets(?n)
It failed too.